# Proof of Why or Why Not some equivalence holds

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

How do I prove that this equivalence
$$\lnot\exists x\,\forall y\,(P(x)\Rightarrow\lnot Q(x,y))\equiv \forall x\,\exists y\,(P(x)\land Q(x,y))$$
holds or not?

I remember that $A\implies B\equiv\lnot A\lor B$. Would this help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few more equivalences you need to remember: $\neg\exists\equiv\forall\neg$,  $\neg\forall\equiv\exists\neg$, and 
$$\neg(p\to q)\equiv(p\land\neg q) \tag{NegImp}
$$
The last follows from the equivalence you remember plus De Morgan, plus  $q\equiv\neg\neg q$, which is another equivalence you'll need. Can you take it from there?

No? OK, here:
$$\begin{align}
\neg\exists x\forall y\,(P(x)\to \neg Q(x,y)) &\iff \forall x\neg\forall y\,(P(x)\to \neg Q(x,y)) \tag{$\neg\exists\equiv\forall\neg$} \\
&\iff \forall x\exists y\,\neg\,(P(x)\to \neg Q(x,y)) \tag{$\neg\forall\equiv\exists\neg$} \\
&\iff \forall x\exists y\,(P(x)\land \neg\neg Q(x,y)) \tag{by NegImp} \\
&\iff \forall x\exists y\,(P(x)\land Q(x,y)) \tag{$q\equiv\neg\neg q$} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Still not sure. Can you add more?

Comment: There, I added more. PS The tags on the first two lines of the chain of equivalences were interchanged; fixed. Thanks.